# How delete multiply fields in redis hash using ServiceStack.Redis?

Tags: redis, servicestack.redis

```
redisClient.RemoveEntryFromHash(string hashId, string key);
```

can't delete mutilply keys.

i find in IRedisNativeClient Interface

```
int HDel(string hashId, byte[] key);
```

no options to mutil keys

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling your own extension method:

```
    public static void RemoveEntriesFromHash(this IRedisClient client, string hashId, List<string> keys)
    {
        if (keys == null || keys.Count == 0) return;

        var nativeClient = (RedisNativeClient)client;

        var keyBytes = new byte[keys.Count][];

        var i = 0;
        foreach (var key in keys)
        {
            keyBytes[i] = key.ToUtf8Bytes();
            i++;
        }

        nativeClient.HDel(hashId, keyBytes);
    }
```